# Local server multiplayer not working in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My sister and I just updated to 0.11.1, and now one the screen where the name usually shows up to join a game, nothing is there. I can't join even though we're on the same WiFi. Help?!

Comment: Make sure both players have `Local Server Multiplayer` turned on, and check your Wi-Fi strength.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I have the same problem.... (local multiplayer is on the same WIFI)

When we open Pocket Edition the first time, the multiplayer world appears, but the player just gets disconnected when the player tries to join me a second time. It doesn't appear anymore. Nothing appears.

We found a solution but it has some problems.

- It lags not on gameplay but on something like your soul is walking but your body is staying put or not moving.
- It disconnects you with no reason.
- You have to save his or her IP.

Go to "edit external" and type the ip in address. Then save. It may appear offline, but just tap the server or multiplayer worlds IP you saved.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: The IP is not the same for everyone. You will need to find out the IP of their device yourself.